# How to get a KML of Wikipedia POIs?

Tags: geoserver, web-mapping

I'm looking at the possibility of using a kml layer in a 'geoserver' to provide attribute information on a point. Is there a KML file for the Wikipedia Places articles as it is used in Google earth or it is a Google 'locked' functionality?

Comment: No the official one but works - http://wikimapia.org/ge.kml

Comment: Have you looked at wikilocation.org? Doesn't return KML, but it does return XML and JSON.

Comment: See this [postgis dump](http://toolserver.org/~kolossos/wp-world/pg-dumps/wp-world), for [database structure](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_Diskussion:WikiProjekt_Georeferenzierung/Wikipedia-World/news#Database_Structure_postGIS) Both resources find through wikipedia links from article http://amercader.net/dev/wikipedia

Comment: Thanks @ThomasG77, even better than what I sought! There is really no 'explicit answer' entry here (apart from the comments) but I'd consider myself answered.

Comment: @ThomasG77 could you please add your comment as an answer so this thread does not reappear on the unanswered questions list? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can see this [postgis dump](http://toolserver.org/~kolossos/wp-world/pg-dumps/wp-world), and find also the [database structure](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_Diskussion%3aWikiProjekt_Georeferenzierung/Wikipedia-World/news#Database_Structure_postGIS)

Both resources were found through wikipedia links from article http://amercader.net/dev/wikipedia